# How to Bind Property in View Model with Picker in View in Xamarin.Forms MVVM

Tags: xamarin.forms, picker

First of all, i am sorry if my english is bad.
I want to make a translator apps, this apps are the same like google translate, there is **two different picker** that can be use to change the language (source language and language target ) just like this picture
[AppsImages][1]

[picker 1, for change the language source/from ][2]

[picker 2, for change the language target/to][3]

To do the translation, the frontend must send the text you want to translate which is user input, information about source (language source/from), and target (language target/to).
I managed to make this application do the translation via user input, but I did harcode for information about source (language source/from) , and target (language target/to) {not yet the result of the picker}

I want to make when picker1 (picker for language source/from) is clicked, it will change the property **source** in the view model will be set to a string ("en" for english, "kr" for korean and "id" for indonesian), same too for picker2.

[xaml code][4]
[view model][5]

How do I do that?
Thank you..
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/tiyd7.png
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pa7yd.png
[3]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ou5qs.png
[4]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/GInIn.png
[5]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZzSIy.png

Comment: Please add code here in the query itself instead of uploading as an image

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

We just need to create binding on `SelectedItem` property , when the item changes ,the property in viewmodel will get changed as well .

##### Xaml

```
<Picker SelectedItem="{Binding selected}" >
```

##### ViewModel

```
public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

private void NotifyPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] String propertyName = "")
{
    PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
}

private string _selected;
public string selected
{
   get {
        return _selected;
   }
   set
   {
        _selected = value;
        NotifyPropertyChanged();
   }
}
```

Refer to [Responding to item selection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/picker/populating-itemssource#responding-to-item-selection-1).